# ThreadAbortException on retrieving data from Entities db context

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities

on prod application throw an ThreadAbortException during retrieving data from my db context, it's about 1 million rows of data table.
I set intentionnally set a big CommandTimeOut of 5 hours but even though this i have an system.web.httpException Timeout reached. by logging i can get this trace :

```
07/11/2013 09:54 : 
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Le thread a été abandonné.
   à SNIReadSync(SNI_Conn* , SNI_Packet** , Int32 )
   à SNINativeMethodWrapper.SNIReadSync(SafeHandle pConn, IntPtr& packet, Int32 timeout)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSni(DbAsyncResult asyncResult, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadNetworkPacket()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadBuffer()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadByte()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   à System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   à System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   à System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   à System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   à System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   à System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   à LinqKit.ExpandableQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   à System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   à DrillWatcher.DisplaySegment.GetSegmentDataTable(ICollection`1 idDrills, List`1 segmentColumnToDisplay) dans C:\SourcesTFS\JLSA\Main\Source\DrillWatcher\DrillWatcher\DrillWatcher\DisplaySegment.aspx.cs:ligne 262
   à DrillWatcher.DrillWatcher.MakeCsvFile(DataTable source, Boolean withSegment) dans C:\SourcesTFS\JLSA\Main\Source\DrillWatcher\DrillWatcher\DrillWatcher\DrillWatcher.aspx.cs:ligne 989
```

Code :

```
 public static DataTable GetSegmentDataTable(ICollection<long> idDrills, List<string> segmentColumnToDisplay)
        {
            var predicat = PredicateBuilder.True<DrillSegments>();
            Expression<Func<DrillSegments, bool>> exp = segments => idDrills.Contains(segments.DrillId);
            predicat = predicat.And(exp);

            using (var dqe = new DrillQuerierEntities { CommandTimeout = 18000})
            {

                try
                {
                    //Nom du forage
                    var result = dqe.DrillSegments.Include("DrillSegmentInfo.DrillSegmentInfoExtraData").AsExpandable().Where(predicat).OrderBy(x => x.SequenceNumber).ToList(); // first toList so querying db
                    var segmentDataTable = new DataTable("DrillSegments");
-------------
```

Any idea about this strange exception ?
Thx for advance

Comment: put more information please your code what is the problem exactly we can not find a magic soultion for you?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the ASP.NET request/page timeout. ASP.NET aborts the thread when the timeout is reached. This also happens when the worker process shuts down, maybe due to a new code deployment. Increase the request timeout. I think the property is called `ScriptTimeout`.